# Python thread in socket chat application won't start

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, networking, chat

I'm new to python, and I'm trying to write a simple chat application, featuring a server which runs a thread that accepts from and transmits messages to connected clients, and a client which runs two threads that send messages to and accept messages from the server respectively.  Here's the code

Server:

```
import socket
import sys
import thread


def receiveAndDeliverMessage(conn):
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1040)
        if not data: break
        print(data)
        conn.send(data) 
    conn.close

HOST = ''   # Localhost
PORT = 8888 # Arbitrary non-privileged port

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) #Create a TCP/IP socket
print 'Socket created'

#Bind socket to local host and port
try:
    sock.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as msg:
    print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()

print 'Socket bind complete'

#Start listening on socket
sock.listen(10)
print 'Socket now listening'


# Create threads for receiving a connection from client and receiving data from client

while True:
    connection, address = sock.accept() #Accept method returns a tupule      containing a new connection and the address of the connected client 
    print 'Connected with ' + address[0] + ':' + str(address[1])

    try:
        thread.start_new_thread(receiveAndDeliverMessage, (connection))
    except:
        print ("Error: unable to start thread")
sock.close()
```

Client:

```
#Socket client example in python

import socket   #for sockets
import sys  #for exit
import thread

def sendMessage():
    count = 0
    while (count < 3):

        message = raw_input('Write message to send to server: ');
        count = count + 1
        print 'message '+str(count)+': '+(message)

        try :
            #Send the whole string
            sock.sendall(message)
        except socket.error:
            #Send failed
            print 'Send failed'
            sys.exit()

        print 'Message sent successfully to server'


def receiveMessage():
    reply = sock.recv(1024)
    print reply#Print the message received from server


#create an INET, STREAMing socket
try:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except socket.error:
    print 'Failed to create socket'
    sys.exit()

print 'Socket Created'

serverHost = 'localhost'
serverPort = 8888

try:
    remote_ip = socket.gethostbyname(serverHost)

except socket.gaierror:
    #could not resolve
    print 'Hostname could not be resolved. Exiting'
    sys.exit()

#Connect to remote server
sock.connect((remote_ip , serverPort))

print 'Socket Connected to ' + serverHost + ' on ip ' + remote_ip

try:
    thread.start_new_thread(receiveMessage, ())
except:
    print ("Error: unable to start receive message thread")


try:
    thread.start_new_thread(sendMessage, ())
except:
    print ("Error: unable to start send message thread")



sock.close()#Close socket to send eof to server
```

Now every time a client is opened, instead of the thread which runs receiveAndDelivermessage function running on the server, the exception gets thrown. So I get the "Error: unable to start thread".  I don't understand why the exception gets thrown. Maybe I haven't yet quite grasped how threads work.  Any help greatly appreciated.  Also each time a client is opened, it gets terminated immediately, after the connection to server is established.

Comment: you are using a catch all except so you don't see the trivial error you have made in your code, `(connection)` is not a tuple with one element, it is just `connection` so `thread.start_new_thread` is throwing a type error because of incorrect argument type.

Comment: @Tadhg McDonald-Jensen  Ok I got it.  corrected it with (connection,address) and now it seems to work fine.  What I still don't get is why the client applications end as soon as the connection is established with server. The second thread which is supposed to trigger sendMessage() method doesn't seem to do that at all.

Answer (score 1):

You swallow the original exception and print out a custom message so it's hard to determine what's causing the issue. So I am going to provide some tips around debugging the issue.

```
    try:
        thread.start_new_thread(receiveAndDeliverMessage, (connection))
    except:
        print ("Error: unable to start thread")
```

You are catching all types of exception in one `except` block which is quite bad. Even if you do so, try to find the message -

```
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
```

Or you can also get the full traceback instead of just printing the exception:

```
import traceback
tb = traceback.format_ex(ex)
```